# How to accumulate the rows in a column using polars::prelude::fold_exprs?

Tags: rust, rust-polars

In [this handbook](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/dsl/folds.html) is an example how to utilise the function [`polars::prelude::fold_exprs`](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/prelude/fn.fold_exprs.html) to accumulate the row values over multiple columns **horizontally**.

```
let df = df!(
    "a" => &[1, 2, 3],
    "b" => &[10, 20, 30],
)?;

let out = df
    .lazy()
    .select([fold_exprs(lit(0), |acc, x| Ok(Some(acc + x)), [col("*")]).alias("sum")])
    .collect()?;
println!("{}", out);
```

The output is:

```
shape: (3, 1)
┌─────┐
│ sum │
│ --- │
│ i64 │
╞═════╡
│ 11  │
│ 22  │
│ 33  │
└─────┘
```

**Question:** How can I accumulate the row values over the single column `col(b)` **vertically** using the `fold_exprs` function to get the following output:

```
shape: (3, 1)
┌─────┐
│ sum │
│ --- │
│ i64 │
╞═════╡
│ 10  │
│ 30  │
│ 60  │
└─────┘
```

I'm looking for something like:

```
let out = df
    .lazy()
    .select([fold_exprs(lit(0), |acc, x| Ok(Some(acc + x)), [col("b")]).alias("sum")])
    .collect()?;
```

where I replaced `col("*")` with `col("b")`: How do I have to modify the closure `|acc, x| Ok(Some(acc + x))` to get my desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a cumulative sum, you can just use the [`cumsum(reverse: bool)`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/polars/prelude/enum.Expr.html#method.cumsum) function (needs feature `cum_agg`).

```rust
let df = df!(
    "a" => &[1, 2, 3],
    "b" => &[10, 20, 30],
)
.unwrap()
.lazy()
.with_column(col("b").cumsum(false).alias("b_summed"));

println!("{:?}", df.collect()?);
```

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬──────────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ b_cumsum │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---      │
│ i32 ┆ i32 ┆ i32      │
╞═════╪═════╪══════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 10  ┆ 10       │
│ 2   ┆ 20  ┆ 30       │
│ 3   ┆ 30  ┆ 60       │
└─────┴─────┴──────────┘
```

For arbitrary cumulative functions you can drop down into [`map`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/polars/prelude/enum.Expr.html#method.map).

```
let df = df!(
    "a" => &[1, 2, 3],
    "b" => &[10, 20, 30],
)
.unwrap()
.lazy()
.with_column(
    col("b")
        .map(
            |b| {
                let b = b.i32()?;
                Ok(Some(
                    b.into_iter()
                        .scan(("".to_owned(), true), |(s, is_first), x| {
                            if !*is_first {
                                s.push(',');
                            }
                            *is_first = false;

                            s.push_str(x.map(|x| x.to_string()).as_deref().unwrap_or(""));
                            Some(s.clone())
                        })
                        .collect::<Utf8Chunked>()
                        .into_series(),
                ))
            },
            GetOutput::from_type(DataType::Utf8),
        )
        .alias("b_cumstr"),
);

println!("{:?}", df.collect()?);
```

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬──────────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ b_cumstr │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---      │
│ i32 ┆ i32 ┆ str      │
╞═════╪═════╪══════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 10  ┆ 10       │
│ 2   ┆ 20  ┆ 10,20    │
│ 3   ┆ 30  ┆ 10,20,30 │
└─────┴─────┴──────────┘
```